# JSON response with JAX-RS

Tags: json, jaxb, jax-rs

I have a simple POJO that i convert to a JSON Object.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Data {
    public Data(){}
    private int roll;
    private String name;
    public int getRoll() {
        return roll;
    }
    public void setRoll(int roll) {
        this.roll = roll;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

This converts to a simple JSON object as

```
{
name: "Adrian",
roll: 77
}
```

This part is fine. Now all my json retuns in my system, will include the object in a data named object lile

```
{
app_name:abc,
app_version:1
data:
{
   user :
   {
     name: "Adrian",
     roll: 77
   }

}
```

What ever type of object i send to the client, i want them to be of this type. Can anyone show me how i can do this ?

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to wrap your `Data` instance into some kind of wrapper, write a class with the proper JAXB annotations:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class DataWrapper {

    private Data data;
    private String app_name;
    private int app_version;

    // Constructors, Getter, Setter
}
```

Then your JAX-RS method would create such a `DataWrapper` and return it:

```
@GET
public Response getDataWrapper() {
    DataWrapper dw = new DataWrapper(app_name, app_version, new Data(...));
    return Response.ok(dw).build();
}
```